# (Corona SDK) Facebook - Invite all friends using facebook.showDialog( "apprequests" )

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk, invite

I'm using the code below to log in into Facebook and show a popup that let's my users invite their friends, but actually, is it possible to invite them one by one, instead of all in one go.

```
local function facebookListener( event )

print( "event.name:" .. event.name )  --"fbconnect"
print( "isError: " .. tostring( event.isError ) )
print( "didComplete: " .. tostring( event.didComplete ) )
print( "event.type:" .. event.type )  --"session", "request", or "dialog"

if ( "session" == event.type ) then
    if ( "login" == event.phase ) then
        local access_token = event.token
        facebook.showDialog( "apprequests", { message="You should download this game!" } )
    elseif ("loginFailed" == event.phase)then

    end

elseif ( "request" == event.type ) then
    print("facebook request")
    if ( not event.isError ) then
        local response = json.decode( event.response ) 
    end

elseif ( "dialog" == event.type ) then
    print( "dialog", event.response )
end
end

facebook.login( fbAppID, facebookListener, { "user_friends", "email",   "publish_actions", "user_birthday" } )
```

So as you can see, I'm using facebook.showDialog(). If my request cannot be accomplished, is there another way to invite my friends selecting all of them by using a button?

By the way, I've got 3 other questions for you:

1) The code above it is working both on Android and iOS -but- while when I send a request from an iOS device, the other person receive the notification, on Android this doesn't happen (and so when I send a request from an Android device, the other person does not receive the notification).

2) Is there a sort of "onComplete" on facebook.showDialog()? I want to reward my users when they invite their   friends

3) Is there a way to prevent Facebook to login every time I relaunch my App? As far as I heard, there should be a token that lasts for about 60 days, but as I said, my app keeps login into Facebook every time I relaunch it.

Thanks.

Comment: _“ want to reward my users when they invite their friends”_ – you are not allowed to do that. (At most, you can reward them for _successful_ invites, i.e. when one of the friends they invited actually becomes a user of your app as well – but only then, and not before.) And it is a deliberate choice by Facebook to only allow the user to select friends one by one manually, and not “all” in one go – to keep the whole thing less spammy. Users should only invite friends they think might actually want to use the app, and not spam their requests to just everyone in their friend list.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

When the users closes the invitation dialog, you will receive a callback to the same facebookListener you sent to init. 
The `event.type` will be equal to `"dialog"`, and `event.response` will be a URI formed string that will tell you who was invited (if at all).
(check out [showDialog doc](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/facebook/showDialog.html) and [fbconnect docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/fbconnect/index.html)).
Then, just go over the URI string and retrieve all the fbid's that were sent invitations. These are the friends that were invited, and you can reward your player however you want.